# Shopify with REST API Logging

Tags: rest, delphi, shopify

I am updating some code that I have already working using a http request for example

https://api:password@mystore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-07/products.json?created_at_min=2022-01-01T00:00:00&status=any&limit=250

but I need to change it so that I can use REST as I need to access shopify's pagination.

I Have found the following code on the internet

```
uses
  System.Net.HttpClient,
  System.Net.HttpClientComponent,
  System.JSON;

var
  client: TNetHTTPClient;
  response: IHTTPResponse;
  json: TJSONObject;
begin
  client := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
  try
    client.BaseURL := 'https://myshopify.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-07';
    client.ContentType := 'application/json';
    client.CustomHeaders['X-Shopify-Access-Token'] := 'YourAccessToken';

    response := client.Get('/products.json');
    json := TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(response.ContentAsString) as TJSONObject;

    try
      // Access the JSON values by name or index
      ShowMessage(json.GetValue('title').Value);
    finally
      json.Free;
    end;

  finally
    client.Free;
  end;
end.
```

My question is how can I change this so it uses REST, I can access the data by passing the secret in URL but this fails if I Want subsequent pages.

In my rest example I can set the
REST.BaseURL:=https://api:password@mystore.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-07/products.json?created_at_min=2022-01-01T00:00:00&status=any&limit=250

However when shopify returns the linkid - it will not allow you to do this and the example above seems the correct way?

So basically how to do mimic

```
 client.CustomHeaders['X-Shopify-Access-Token'] := 'YourAccessToken';
```

Using REST?

I am using delphi 10.3.2

Thanks in advance
Phil

Comment: Can add a since_id parameter (Return only products after the specified ID) with the value from the last product returned.

Comment: Hi Brian, I do that currently with my orders in my https request, but dont think it works on customers, and ideally I wan to run a query on it using customer.json/query.json - but thanks!

Comment: The GET to retrieve a list of customers has the same since_id parameter. The get list of customers with query does not however.

Comment: Looks like page_info is a temporary possibly secure value and takes the place of authorization headers. So just use the url for the direction you want to do: next or previous.

Comment: Have you tried adding a [parameter](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Client.TRESTRequestParameter) to `TRestClient`'s `Params` collection? `Kind := pkHTTPHEADER; Name := 'X-Shopify-Access-Token'; Value := 'YourAccessToken';`

Comment: @PeterWolf  Thanks - i had tried that - but it failed -but I have changed the token and I think that's fixed it now :-)

The only issue now Is if I look at the link returned from the hdrs to determine the next page I need and pass them back to shopify it tells me the page info contains an invalid value?  Could the rest client be scrambling the return header?

Comment: I have fixed my issue - I Needed to take the > from the reply out ;-)

Comment: That's not the correct approach. Shopify returns HTTP link header in response according to [the specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Link). It can also contain multiple links separated by comma. You need to parse the header value and look for `rel="first"`, `rel="previous"`, `rel="next"` and `rel="last"` parameters. Shopify API doesn't guarantee the order of the links in the header.